# matlab: sum of f(k_i,x) where k_i are scalars and x is a matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix-multiplication

Any idea how to formulate this sum other than using a loop?

sum(i) f(k(i),x) where k_i are some entries of a vector and x is a matrix.

Currently what I'm doing is this, but I'd rather have a general solution:

```
for ii=1:length(k)
psi=psi+f(k(ii),x)
end
```

If it's any concern:

```
f(k,x)=g(k)*exp(k*x)
```

Comment: The definition of `f` and `g` makes all the difference.  If they can operator on a vector.  What is `g`?  An array or function?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, x is a matrix. g(k) can take vector input.

Comment: Can you add an example of input and expected output?

Comment: sure, here's a concrete example `x=linspace(-5,5,300);
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,x);
k=linspace(-10,10,400);
psi=zeros(size(xx));
for ii=1:length(k)
    psi=psi+exp(-k(ii)^2/4)*exp(1i*k(ii)*xx);
end
imagesc(abs(psi))`

Comment: Your question case is not clear, you better add simple matlab code for us to see how those variables are defined and structred.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `g` can take a vector input and returns a vector result of the same size, and that `x` is just a scalar

```
f=@(k,x) g(k).*exp(k*x);
psi=sum(f(k,x))
```

or if `g` can't be or isn't able to take vector input, you can do

```
g=@(k) arrayfun(g,k);
```

and then define `f` as before.

Comment: Thank, but the problem here is that because x is a matrix the sum is not the sum of matrices f(k1,x)+f(k2,x)+.... but some summation of the columns weighted with the vector k.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to sum only specific rows?
If so, this will do it:

```
a= [1 2 3 4;
    5 2 7 2;
    0 0 2 3];

k= [1 3]; %rows selection for sum

result= sum(a(k,:))
```

Comment: not quite, i want to sum the matrices (for example) k(1)^2*exp(k(1)*a)+k(2)^2*exp(k(2)*a)